# How to do Ajax Post request in phonegap

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using phonegap and jquery mobile to build a web app, django on the server side. First, i start out from index.html page,and inject a login form from server into index.html and change page to the jquery mobile page containing the sign in form. But the problem is that the form is getting submitted but not in ajax, but if i test it in web browser,it works. I have already white listed the domain name in config.xml file.
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
        <div class="app" style="display:none;">
            <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
          <div data-role="header">
            <h1>DOCTORSLOG</h1>
          </div>
          <div data-role="content">
          </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
             $(function(){
              $.ajax({
                url: 'http://doctorslog.net/mobile/login-test/',
                success: function(data){
                  //append the response(sign-in.html) to the body
                  $('body').append(data);
                }
              });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**sign-in.html**

```
<div data-role="page" data-fullscreen="true" id="login">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <h1 id="title">DOCTORSLOG</h1>
        </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                    <form  id="sign_in_form" method="post" action="http://doctorslog.net/mobile/login/">{% csrf_token %}
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="id_username" style="font-size: 1.3em;line-height: 350%;">Username</label>
                        <input id="id_username" style="font-size: 1.8em;font-weight: bold;font-family: Tahoma,Verdana,serif;" type="text" maxlength="30" name="username" autocomplete="off">
                        </div>
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">

                        <label for="id_password" style="font-size: 1.3em;line-height: 350%;">Password</label>
                        <input id="id_password" style="font-size: 1.8em;font-weight: bold;font-family: Tahoma,Verdana,serif;" type="password" name="password">
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: 100%;text-align: center;font-size: 1.6em;">
                        <input id="sign-in-btn" type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Sign me in" />
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% firstof next '/home/' %}"/>
                        <input id="hiddenID" type="hidden" name="regID" value=""/>
                    </form>
            </div>
      <script>
           $(function(){
               //change active page to this page and since it is a jquery mobile page with data-role=page,i expect automatic ajax submission on clicking submit button
               $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change','#login');
               $('#sign_in_form').trigger('create');
           });
       </script>
  </div>
```

The question is, if i can make Ajax GET request,why can not i make POST request. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: From what I see you're not actually doing an Ajax Post request.  You're just doing a default form post request.  Try implementing the Ajax.

Comment: @Drew B From what i learnt, in jQuery Mobile form submissions are automatically handled using Ajax, unless i set data-ajax=false on the form tag. By the way i also tried ajax submission , but did not work.Is it because of trying to do Ajax Post from local file(index.html) ? Thanks for the response,looking forward for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have solved this issue by disabling jquery mobile default form hijacking by setting `data-ajax="false"` on the form tag and submitting the form by `$.ajax` . Nothing like `$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages` worked. And i also have set Access-Control-Allow-Origin response headers on the server side , really did not know if this is required.
Here is the script to submitform -

```
$(function(){
    $('#sign_in_form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.mobile.loading('show');
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        var data = $(this).serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
              beforeSend:function(jqXHR,settings){
                 jqXHR.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
                  },
              url:url,
              type:'POST',
              data:data,
              crossDomain:false,
              success: function(data){
              $.mobile.loading('hide');
              $('body').append(data);
              }
             });
          });
        });
```